# Task.Status should be Running but shows RanToCompletion

Tags: c#, uwp, task

I'm puzzled with this situation, where a class has a method that launches two periodic `Task`s and then a property is used to check if both `Task`s are still running or not, but the result is unexpected. Here is the code (simplified):

```cs
public partial class UdpClientConnector
{        
    Task localListener;

    Task periodicSubscriber;

    bool keepWorking = false;

    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get
        {
            if ((localListener != null) && (periodicSubscriber != null))
            {
                return (localListener.Status == TaskStatus.Running) &&
                       (periodicSubscriber.Status == TaskStatus.Running);
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        keepWorking = true;
        localListener = new Task(() => LocalListenerWorker());
        localListener.Start();

        periodicSubscriber = new Task(() => PeriodicSubscriberWorker());
        periodicSubscriber.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        keepWorking = false;
        localListener.Wait();
        periodicSubscriber.Wait();
    }

    async void LocalListenerWorker()
    {
        while (keepWorking)
        {
            // Do some work and then wait a bit
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }

    async void PeriodicSubscriberWorker()
    {
        while (keepWorking)
        {
            // Do some (other) work and then wait a bit
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

To test this boilerplate I used the following:

```cs
UdpClientConnector connector = new UdpClientConnector();

// This assert is successful because the two Tasks are not yet started
Assert.IsTrue(!connector.IsRunning);

// Starts the tasks and wait a bit
Connector.Start();
Task.Delay(2000).Wait();

// This fails 
Assert.IsTrue(connector.IsRunning);
```

When I've tried to debug the test case, I've found that two Tasks are in the `RanToCompletion` state, which is unexpected due the fact that both tasks are just loops and should not terminate until `keepWorking` becomes false.

I've tried also to start the Tasks using `Task.Factory.StartNew(..)` with same results.

What I'm missing? Thank you!

Comment: You're not doing anything to make sure that the change of `keepWorking` to `true` is visible in the other tasks. I would *kind of* expect it to be okay, but I'd start by seeing whether it makes a difference if you change `keepWorking` to be a property that uses locks or `Interlocked` to ensure freshness. (Maybe just making the variable volatile would help, but the volatile keyword scares me.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've just tried with the `volatile` keyword (which I was not aware of before now), but nothing changed. Also `keepWorking` is set to `true` before the call to `Start()` and the two Tasks access it just read-only, so I didn't `lock` the access. During the debug I've also noticed that the code actually cycles in the loop as expected...

Comment: Oh, hang on - I see the problem, I think.

Comment: Why are your methods `async void`? That provides no mechanism for the caller to know when it completes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with how you start the tasks, and indeed the task methods.

```
localListener = new Task(() => LocalListenerWorker());
```

That task will complete when `LocalListenerWorker` returns - which it will do pretty much *immediately* (when it hits the first `await` expression). It doesn't wait for the asynchronous operation to actually complete (i.e. the loop to finish).

`async void` methods should almost *never* be used - they're basically only there to support event handlers.

I suggest you rewrite your methods to return `Task`, and then use `Task.Run` to start them, passing in a method group:

```
Task.Run(LocalListenerWorker);
...

private async Task LocalListenerWorker()
{
    // Body as before
}
```

The task by `Task.Run` will only complete when the task returned by `LocalListenerWorker` completes, which is when the loop body finishes.

Here's a complete demo:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task task1 = Task.Run(Loop);
        // Don't do this normally! It's just as a simple demo
        // in a console app...
        task1.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("First task done");

        Task task2 = new Task(() => Broken());
        task2.Start();
        // Don't do this normally! It's just as a simple demo
        // in a console app...
        task2.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Second task done");
    }

    static async Task Loop()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }

    static async void Broken()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The output shows:

```
0
1
2
3
4
First task done
Second task done
```

The first task behaves as expected, and only completes when the first async method has really completed. The second task behaves like your current code: it completes as soon as the second async method has returned - which happens almost immediately due to the `await`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your much appreciated explanation solved the issue.

Comment: Does this apply even if the method being called contains an async iterator (`async foreach(...)`)?

Comment: @dotNET: I don't know exactly what you mean by "this" - it seems to me that you should investigate for yourself, and then ask a new question with details if you need to.